# Set InArgument when launching a workflow programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011

Is there any way to set the value of a workflow's `InArgument` parameter from another workflow when launching it programmatically ?

Here's how I launch it:

```
var req = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest { WorkflowId = new Guid(WorkflowGuids.RenewalWorkflowId), EntityId = theContact.Id };
service.Execute(req);
```

I can catch the `EntityId` value back in the other workflow in `context.PrimaryEntityId` but I am at a loss as to how to populated the arguments and retrieve them on the other side.

Is this possible ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InArgument` are defined at step level, not at workflow level.

When a workflow is executed (by a trigger, on-demand or by code) you have the record Id.

You can create a custom workflow activity to fetch other data related (or not connected at all) with your record Id and make it as `OutArgument` so will be available as input for the `InArgument` you want to set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Guido. Are you saying the workflow code above should have `OutArguments` matchings the `InArguments` of the workflow I'm launching ?

Comment: the steps have InArgument/OutArgument, not the workflow itself. If you have some steps that requires some input, the only thing is to create a custom workflow activity to provide them the value for the InArgument.